# android spinner not clickable on version greater than 3.0?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I use custom spinner in my android application but the spinner not clickable
on version greater than 3.0 and it is perfectly work on version less than
3.0. please anybody tell  me why this happen.

[image]

this is my main spinner.xml

```
   <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/bldngSpnrBldng"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selectors"
                    android:prompt="@string/select_building"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

Here what happen when i open graphical Layout then encountered exception like

> Failed to parse file ....\res\drawable\spinner_selector_selected.xml
>   Failed to parse file  ....\res\drawable\spinner_selectors.xml
>   Resouce id 0x1010081 is not of type STYLE (instead attr)
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

**Que:How to fix the above error?**

spinner_selector_selected.xml for border line and spinner image at corner of spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>


                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/gray" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                <padding 
                    android:bottom="3dp" 
                    android:left="3dp" 
                    android:right="3dp" 
                    android:top="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/pressed_color"/>
            </shape>

        </item>

        <item>
            <bitmap 
                android:gravity="bottom|right" 
                android:src="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_new_theme_bs" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>

</item>
```

updated 
following is the spinner listener.

```
spinnerPhase.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) 
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            ........

        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

use OnItemSelectedListener interface instead of click listener.
it is available under android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener. Import it and implement its methods.
More details available at [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Two ways to solve the issue

1. Change your spinnerMode to dialog like `android:spinnerMode="dialog "`
2. Replace: `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"` with

   ```
   android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"
   ```

**And second approach requires API 11**